# Best markup language for small articles, letters, resumes

Tags: latex, markup, asciidoc

I would like to have a suggestion on the right choice for
a markup language. I need to write some short technical 
articles, business letters and a resume. 
The desired output are:

- PDF
- HTML
- RTF/DOCX

The following are other requirements:

- Right alignment of blocks
- Use of symbols (for email, mobile address)
- Table without borders
- Page numbering and footer

The following is an example of letter. With what language would 
you make it?
I do not use WORD/OPENOFFICE because I want to generate the documents
starting from data in a MySQL database.
At the moment I am using Latex with moderncv style but I do not
consider tools such as latex2word good enough to make a RTF/DOCX
output.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



                                                                                                                                  Mark Jeronimo,
                                                                                                                          54 Campbell Parade,
                                                                                                                                     Bondi Beach,
                                                                                                                                     Sydney 2022
                                                                                                                                  NSW- Australia
                                                                                                                       cell.: +61-0421-233732
                                                                                                      email.: mark.jeronimo@gmail.com



                                                                                                                                      April 8, 2013


Dear Sir or Madam,

                                                        Re: Proposal for an IT business

With reference to your email, I wish to express my interest in meeting you for the proposal of an IT 
business
bla bla
bla bla


Yours faithfully,

Mark Jeronimo

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 5):

Consider using [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/). It supports many input and output formats, including the ones you specified. For markup, one of the choices there is Markdown with pandoc extensions. The features you asked for are all possible. You can use custom templates in HTML, LaTeX, etc., to stylize things such as tables and page numbers.